# Vertical line on progress bar for notes mark

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm currently creating a customize progress-bar for Youtube player, so i can take notes for learning on the video.

I wish to insert marks on progress bar at some specific position.

From what i know, i'm thinking about using the border right or left of the div to do the vertical line at the position. But, **the marks positions only at the right positions if the first progress-bar is at 100%**, since the 3 marks depend on the progress-bar parent.  I don't know what to do. Maybe there is another better approach.

Here is the code i'm thinking about

```
<div class="progress">
    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success" role="progressbar" style="width:100%"">
      <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success marks" role="progressbar" style="width:40%">
        Free Space
      </div>
      <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-warning marks" role="progressbar" style="width:10%">
        Warning
      </div>
      <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-danger marks" role="progressbar" style="width:20%">
        Danger
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
div.marks{
  background-color:transparent;
  border-left:2px solid red;
}
```

I publish and example of the page i create, so you can understand better what i'm trying to do.
http://nghekinh.herokuapp.com/

At this moment, only the track 181 has notes, I loaded it by default so you can see. I wish to put marks on the progress-bars at the position of the notes.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

You means like this bro.I suggest using flex property.I remove float left property and added a little css code ;) .I hope you like it.

```css
.playerPB {
    padding-left: 0px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 7px 7px;
}

li {
    list-style-type: none;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    height: 43px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.pull-left {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin-right: 20px;
}

.progress {
    height: 32px;
    background-color: rgb(216, 212, 212);
    flex:auto;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. From what I understand of the css code above, it does align my timestamp on the left and my progress-bars at the right. It's indeed more easy to see.  But what I'm concerning more right now, it's how can I put the vertical line on the progress bars at a certain position (example, on udemy, we can add notes on the progress bar of the videos)

Comment: I thought you're stack with css . But the answer your are asking for is I can't explain .Sorry ;) .But I manage to solve the first problem " the marks positions only at the right positions if the first progress-bar is at 100% ".

Comment: Actually, what I mean by "mark", it's the  "vertical line"  on progress-bars. I used it as a mark for the note. Thank  you for helping me to  be clearer. But your code makes the interface more agreeable to see. Thanks